# can't fresh install 18.04.4 (gfxpayload)

Tags: boot, nvidia

Can't make fresh install of 18.04.4 (Corei9, Samsung NVME 970, Nvidia GT7300) - getting to GRUB when neither "Trying without install" nor "Install" works - black screen.

"nomodeset" does not help, however changing "gfxpayload=keep" to 'gfxpayload=1920x1080" results in several seconds delay but then starts up installer.

once setup is done and reboots ubuntu boots just fine without any changes in GRUB.
is there any way to avoid manual grub steps during first boot?

Comment: Did you verify your downloaded ISO as perfect? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then the write to your install media was flawless? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card or any install media)